# Filter ListView from custom base adapter

Tags: android

I am trying to implement the search in the Custom ListView. I am able to search in my list. But the problem with my adapter is once the query string is not available in the list even if i backspace my string and write the correct string it's not able to search it. And my other question is how can I refresh the list with my old list which was present before the search.

Here is my code:

```
public class ChartListAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable {
    ArrayList<ChartModel> list;
    Context context;

    public ChartListAdapter(ArrayList<ChartModel> list, Context context) {
        this.list = list;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        if(list != null) {
            return list.size();
        } else {
            return 0;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return list.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return i;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

        if(view == null) {
            view = View.inflate(context, R.layout.chart_card, null);
        }

        TextView chart_name = view.findViewById(R.id.chart_name);
        SwitchCompat switchCompat = view.findViewById(R.id.chart_selected);
        switchCompat.setTag(list.get(i).getChart_id());
        chart_name.setText(list.get(i).getChart_name());
        switchCompat.setChecked(list.get(i).getCard_selected());

        switchCompat.setOnCheckedChangeListener((compoundButton, b) -> {
            String getTag = compoundButton.getTag().toString();
            Toast.makeText(context, getTag  + " is selected :" +  b, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        });


        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        return new Filter() {
            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {

                FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
                if(constraint == null || constraint.length() == 0){
                    filterResults.count = list.size();
                    filterResults.values = list;

                }else{
                    ArrayList<ChartModel> resultsModel = new ArrayList<>();
                    String searchStr = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();

                    for(ChartModel itemsModel:list){
                        if(itemsModel.getChart_id().contains(searchStr)){
                            resultsModel.add(itemsModel);

                        }
                        filterResults.count = resultsModel.size();
                        filterResults.values = resultsModel;
                    }


                }

                return filterResults;
            }

            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {

                list = (ArrayList<ChartModel>) results.values;
                notifyDataSetChanged();


            }
        };
    }
}
```

Any suggestion will be of great help. Thank you for your time.

Comment: its because you are using a single list for searching in your adapter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your adapter class like this

```
public class ChartListAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable {
ArrayList<ChartModel> list;
ArrayList<ChartModel> filteredList;
Context context;

public ChartListAdapter(ArrayList<ChartModel> list, Context context) {
    this.list = list;
    this.filteredList = list;
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    if(filteredList != null) {
        return filteredList.size();
    } else {
        return 0;
    }

}

@Override
public Object getItem(int i) {
    return filteredList.get(i);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int i) {
    return i;
}

@Override
public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {

    if(view == null) {
        view = View.inflate(context, R.layout.chart_card, null);
    }

    TextView chart_name = view.findViewById(R.id.chart_name);
    SwitchCompat switchCompat = view.findViewById(R.id.chart_selected);
    switchCompat.setTag(filteredList.get(i).getChart_id());
    chart_name.setText(filteredList.get(i).getChart_name());
    switchCompat.setChecked(filteredList.get(i).getCard_selected());

    switchCompat.setOnCheckedChangeListener((compoundButton, b) -> {
        String getTag = compoundButton.getTag().toString();
        Toast.makeText(context, getTag  + " is selected :" +  b, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    });


    return view;
}

@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    return new Filter() {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {

            FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
            if(constraint == null || constraint.length() == 0){
                filteredList = list;

            }else{
                ArrayList<ChartModel> resultsModel = new ArrayList<>();
                String searchStr = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();

                for(ChartModel itemsModel:list){
                    if(itemsModel.getChart_id().contains(searchStr)){
                        resultsModel.add(itemsModel);

                    }
                    filteredList = resultsModel;
                }

            }
              filterResults.values = filteredList;

            return filterResults;
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {

            filteredList = (ArrayList<ChartModel>) results.values;
            notifyDataSetChanged();


        }
    };
}
```

}

Comment: Thank you. It worked perfectly. How I can reset the search and get back the complete ArrayList. How can I do that?